# biblatex: printing separate bibliographies

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

I'm using `biblatex` and I have it set up like this:

In my bib file I have 3 sorts of entrys, online, booklet, and book.

And in my thesis I want them printed separate like this:

```
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Books},type=book, nottype=url, nottype=booklet, nottype=online]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Websites},type=online, nottype=book, nottype=booklet, nottype=url]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Misc},type=booklet]
```

For some reason this won't work, it still puts the websites where the books should be. And vice versa. The booklet thing does work though, it only shows my booklet entries there.

I recently started using `biblatex` so this might be a stupid question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce the behaviour you described -- try my example below. If it works for you, then you have to find out the differences to your setup/bib-file etc. In any case, there's no need to mix `type` and `nottype` in the optional argument of `\printbibliography`, so you shouldn't do it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {A book},
}
@booklet{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {A booklet},
}
@online{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {An online resource},
  url = {none},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography[title={Books},type=book]

\printbibliography[title={Booklets},type=booklet]

\printbibliography[title={Online Resources},type=online]

\end{document}
```

(The filecontents environment is only used to include some external files directly into the example, so that it compiles. It is not necessary for the solution.)

Comment: I basicly copy pasted your solution. But over there, my websites still end up at the printed books.

Comment: Using this now: (still same prob)
`@book{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {A book},
}
@booklet{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {A booklet},
}

@online{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {An online resource},
  url = {none},
}`
And:
`\bibliography{biblio}` in premable
In mainfile:
`\chapter*{Bibliografie}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Boeken},type=book]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Publicaties},type=booklet]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={Websites},type=online]`

Comment: @Toroo: If you do exactly (not basicly) copy-paste and compile my solution, does it still produce the wrong attribution?

Comment: I got it to work now, 1 small question. How can i keep the bibliography istself out of my main file? Everything between `\begin{filecontents}` and `\end{filecontents}`

This way it makes my mainfile kinda messy and big.

Comment: Save the bibliography as separate file (say, `mybiblio.bib`) in your working directory. In the main file, use `\bibliography{mybiblio}`.