# Create a publications and patents stand-alone list

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, subdividing

I would like to create a document containing a list of publications and patents using LaTeX.  This could be a companion to a CV/Resume.

Ideally, I would like to use a `bib` file, but would also like to be able to give sub-headings (ie Journals, Peer Reviewed Conferences, In Review, etc...)

I have found a few examples online, but had no success compiling them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use [biblatex](http://ftp.univie.ac.at/packages/tex/help/Catalogue/entries/biblatex.html). A compilable example that shows how to print separate bibliographies for certain entry types can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10427/biblatex-printing-separate-bibliographies/10443#10443). It is also possible to subdivide the bibliography by keyword (to be defined in the `bib`-file) or category (to be defined at the document level).

Comment: looks like a little bit of a learning curve, but seems to be what I was looking for.  Thanks!