# BibLaTeX: main and secondary bibliographies

Tags: biblatex, subdividing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [biblatex: printing separate bibliographies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10427/biblatex-printing-separate-bibliographies)

I'm writing a PhD thesis in which I intend to include the full contents of an article I wrote. Since I'd like the text to be as close as possible to the version which is published, I'd like to have a dedicated (let 's call it 'secondary') bibliography section for the article at the end of the chapter in which it is included. However, I also want all the references cited in the article to be listed in the 'main' bibliography, at the end of the thesis.

So to sum it up, I have a single bibliographic resource (somefile.bib), two bibliographies (main and secondary) and I want the entries of the secondary to be included in the main.

Currently, I managed to do a part of the job by including the contents of the article in a `refsegment` environment. But then, the entries cited in the article and not in the rest of the thesis do not appear in the main bibliography. A workaround would be to have the `\printbibliography` command take several segments. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think so: my bibliography sources are not differentiated by anything other than 'are they cited in the article or not?', unlike in the question you're pointing. Thank you for reading anyway :) However, I just found the solution and it is pretty obvious: the `refsegment` environment is intended to do that. I just didn't have a proper example in my code to see that things were actually working properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the following example, entries cited only within the `refsegment` *do* also appear in the main bibliography:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{First}

Some text \autocite{A01,B02}.

\begin{refsegment}

\section{Second: An article I wrote}

Some text \autocite{A01,C03}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={References for section~\thesection},
    segment=1]

\end{refsegment}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for providing the right answer with a working example. I simply hadn't understood how the `refsegment` environment works, and I apologize for that.

Comment: @M4urice: No need to apologize. :-)