# nocite{*} exclude

Tags: bibtex, bibunits

I have to put the report of a research trainig group together, where each former PhD student has to write a report with a list of her/his publications. The publications are contained in seperate `.bib` files and I am also using `bibunits`.
The `.bib` files, however, contain their PhD theses (included as an `@phdthesis` entry) which schould not occour in their publications.

How can I still use `\nocite{*}` to list their publications and exclude the PhD theses?

Comment: Pretty sure you can do this in biblatex. Firstly, you can add each student as a 'bibresource', secondly, you can print bibliography of only a certain type of document... http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10427/biblatex-printing-separate-bibliographies use the `nottype` flag to exclude phdthesis.

Comment: @NicholasHamilton Right, with `biblatex` one can use `\printbibliography[nottype=phdthesis]`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can also create a list using `\nocite{<key1>,<key2>,...}` instead of printing all entries by calling `\nocite{*}`.

Comment: When using \nocite{*}, I found the option [resetnumbers=1] to be useful, since otherwise the numbered entries skip the items not included by the filter.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the bibliography style, you can just redefine the `phdthesis` and possibly `mastersthesis` functions. For example, starting from a MWE with `plain.bst`

```
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\nocite*
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

If you copy the original `plain.bst` to a new file `myplain.bst` and replace lines 734--747

```
FUNCTION {mastersthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  "Master's thesis" format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" output.check
  address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

with

```
FUNCTION {mastersthesis}
{
}
```

and lines 763--776

```
FUNCTION {phdthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  new.block
  "PhD thesis" format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" output.check
  address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

with

```
FUNCTION {phdthesis}
{
}
```

and change the MWE to use `myplain.bst`

```
\documentclass{article}
\bibliographystyle{myplain}
\begin{document}
\nocite*
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

gives you the same bibliography without the theses.